# Subspace proof for polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

On a quiz I was asked prove the set of polynomials with degree less than or equal to $2$ such that $p(0)=0$ is a subspace of the set of polynomials with degree at most 2.

I considered the set to be $\{a_1t+a_2t^2:a_1,a_2 \in\textbf{F}\}$

and showed $0=0t+0t^2$

$p+q=(a_1+b_1)t+(a_2+b_2)t^2$ is in the set and

$cp=(ca_1)t+(ca_2)t^2$ is in the set. I have seen another proof and do not know if my way is equivalent? Can someone let me know if my way is correct?

Comment: Your proof looks ok. What does that other proof look like?

Comment: it looks like if $f$ is the $0$ function $f(0)=0$, $(p+q)(0)=0$ and $(cp)(0)=0$

Comment: Subspace of what?

Comment: of the set of polynomials with degree at most 2

Comment: Yep, that would be a correct proof too. (Actually, no offense, both proofs are equally good in this particular case, but this other proof seems to be slightly easier to generalise, e.g. to polynomials of degree at most $2020$, polynomials having value $0$ on $-42$ or general real functions being identically zero on $[-2,2]$ etc. - so it's good to know them both!)

Comment: (Cont'd) Actually what you have done is show that the given set is $\text{span}(t, t^2)$ and spans are always subspaces. What they've shown is that the given set is $\ker(\Phi)$ where $\Phi$ is a *linear* map $f\mapsto f(0)$, and kernels of linear maps are always subspaces. So in effect both proofs have their generalisations.

Answer (score 1):

I think your proof is fine. Perhaps it lacks a bit of preciseness

$$ \text{Let U be the subspace of $P_2(x)$ where} \; U = \{ a_2 x^2+a_1 x + a_0 = q(x) \mid q(0) =0 \} $$

$$ \text{ choose arbitrary} \;\; p_1(x), p_2(x) \in U $$

$$ p_1(0) + p_2(0) = 0+0 = 0 $$ hence closure under addition holds
$$ \text{ take c $\in \mathbb{R} $ \; then for arbitrary p(x) $\in$ U} $$
$$ cp(0) = c(0) = 0 $$ hence closure under scalar multiplication holds

Lastly the zero vector is clearly in the subspace as well and the other axioms of the vector space are inherited.

We conclude $U$ is a vector space itself, by definition a subspace of $ P_2(x) $